# Everyplay demo on android device not working properly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, everyplay

I tried adding everyplay by watching the official everyplay integration video. But when i play it on my android device nothing happening when i press the start record button. Its  shown not uploading at the bottom of the screen always.The everyplay button open everyplay though. But the start recording and stop recording function didnt work. Any help???

Comment: Can you tell which Android device it was, and which Android version are you using? Also, what does IsRecordingSupported() return for that device?

Comment: its an XTouch tablet running android version 4.0.4. I am having issues with getting logcat information from this device..I am working on it now..once I figured it out will let you know...Cheers..

Comment: Everyplay recording works only starting with Android 4.1

Comment: ok.Then that might be the problem. Thank you.